# VS Code User tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I've got a handful of custom tasks in VS Code that I want to share across multiple projects. The tasks are currently installed in `$PROJECT_DIR/.vscode/tasks.json`.

Where should I put my tasks file so that it is loaded by VS Code for all projects (I'm thinking something similar to User vs Workspace settings)?

I've tried `~/.vscode/tasks.json` (I'm not sure if this is a location that VS Code uses or if it's something I created ages ago) and also `$HOME/Library/Application \Support/Code/User/tasks.json` (this is where custom `settings.json` and `keybindings.json` etc. are stored). Neither of these locations works.

At the moment, it seems like I can only have custom tasks defined in each workspace rather than globally. I couldn't see anything in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks). Any pointers welcome?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the specific question about the location of the "user tasks" `tasks.json` file:

- In Ubuntu, it's in `~/.config/Code/User/tasks.json`
- In Windows WSL, it's in `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/tasks.json`

[feel free to edit if you know the location in Mac or other systems]

Answer (score 3):

This question is a duplicate of [Create tasks in Visual Studio Code per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949413/create-tasks-in-visual-studio-code-per-user/60013951#60013951) but I cannot mark it as such as that has not been upvoted or accepted yet.  Reproduced here:

---

It looks like this will be in v1.42, the January 2020 release. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89343 (user level tasks).  And https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1435.

> In addition to having tasks in your .code-workspace file and in
>   tasks.json in your open folder, you can now have tasks in a user level
>   tasks.json next to your user settings.json.
>
> Open a folder that has some tasks. The vscode project is a good
>   example.
>
> Run the Open User Tasks command to create a tasks.json file next to
>   your user settings.json file.
>
> Add a shell or process type task to the new tasks.json. Only those two
>   types of task are supported here.
>
> Run the Run Task command and verify that you see your new user level
>   task. Verify that you can tell that it's a user level task in the task
>   quick pick. Verify that you can configure your user level task by
>   clicking the gear next to it in the quick pick. Verify that you can
>   run the user task.

It is in the Insiders' Build already so presumably v1.42.

-------  From the [1.42 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#user-level-tasks):

> **User level tasks**
>
> Tasks declared in `tasks.json` are now supported at the User Settings
>   level. If you have a build script that you use across many projects,
>   or if you don't want your tasks in a project folder, you can add your
>   tasks in the user `tasks.json` file. You can run the **Tasks: Open User
>   Tasks** command to create user level tasks. These tasks will be
>   available across all folders and workspaces. Only the `shell` and
>   `process` task types are supported here.